# How to check if generic object is an instance of specific class when it actually is even more specific?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have many classes.

```
public abstract class ClassA {}

public class ClassB : ClassA {}

public class ClassC : ClassA {}

public class ClassD : ClassB {}

public class ClassE : ClassB {}

public class ClassF : ClassC {}

public class ClassG : ClassC {}
```

I have an object that is typed as `ClassA`. I want to check if this object is an instance of `ClassB` or not, when it is actually an instance of `D, E, F or G`. Basically test if it is `B, D or E`, by checking if it inherits `B` or is `B`.

`if (obj.GetType == typeof(ClassB)) returns false` when `ClassD` or `ClassE`.

What should I do in that situation without explicitly checking for every single type that inherits from `B`?

Comment: What have you tried already? There are plenty of examples on Stack Overflow showing how to test inheritance relationships in C#. You should use those examples to solve your problem, instead of asking Stack Overflow to write your code for you. Also, when you write "generic", do you really mean "generic", as in a C# generic type? Or are you just misusing the term, and really mean "general"?

Comment: Is the answer [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is)?